# How to set the values, which should be considered equal, for a merge

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)

DT1 <- structure(list(Value_A = c(0.999891903413269, 0.982154309144703, 
0.592188885660591, 0.661057845195792, 0.937776766715946, 0.916698007208248, 
0.0701487169744913, 0.464692536229384, 0.893825143445546, 0.446259881776091
), Cat_A = c("1-5", "1-5", "1-5", "1-5", "1-5", "6-10", "6-10", 
"6-10", "6-10", "6-10")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Value_A Cat_A
     <dbl> <chr>
 1  1.00   1-5  
 2  0.982  1-5  
 3  0.592  1-5  
 4  0.661  1-5  
 5  0.938  1-5  
 6  0.917  6-10 
 7  0.0701 6-10 
 8  0.465  6-10 
 9  0.894  6-10 
10  0.446  6-10 

DT2 <- structure(list(Value_B = c(0.77108614914467, 0.707807008408563, 
0.142130428652957, 0.0790962463426558, 0.0900305847177399, 0.342793229042372, 
0.533475451123892, 0.392646249361294, 0.969809092535721, 0.773003569195185
), Cat_B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Value_B Cat_B
     <dbl> <dbl>
 1  0.771      1
 2  0.708      2
 3  0.142      3
 4  0.0791     4
 5  0.0900     5
 6  0.343      6
 7  0.533      7
 8  0.393      8
 9  0.970      9
10  0.773     10
```

I would like to `merge` these data.frames by `Cat_A` and `Cat_B`, to get:

```
DT_result <- structure(list(Value_A = c(0.999891903413269, 0.982154309144703, 
0.592188885660591, 0.661057845195792, 0.937776766715946, 0.916698007208248, 
0.0701487169744913, 0.464692536229384, 0.893825143445546, 0.446259881776091
), Cat_A = c("1-5", "1-5", "1-5", "1-5", "1-5", "6-10", "6-10", 
"6-10", "6-10", "6-10"), Value_B = c(0.77108614914467, 0.707807008408563, 
0.142130428652957, 0.0790962463426558, 0.0900305847177399, 0.342793229042372, 
0.533475451123892, 0.392646249361294, 0.969809092535721, 0.773003569195185
), Cat_B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Value_A Cat_A Value_B Cat_B
     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1.00   1-5    0.771      1
 2  0.982  1-5    0.708      2
 3  0.592  1-5    0.142      3
 4  0.661  1-5    0.0791     4
 5  0.938  1-5    0.0900     5
 6  0.917  6-10   0.343      6
 7  0.0701 6-10   0.533      7
 8  0.465  6-10   0.393      8
 9  0.894  6-10   0.970      9
10  0.446  6-10   0.773     10
```

I know I can use `by.x="Cat_A"` and `by.y="Cat_B"`:

```
merge(DT1, DT2, by.x="Cat_A", by.y="Cat_B", all.x=TRUE)
```

but how do I tell `merge` that `1,2,3,4 and 5` should merge with `1-5`, etc?

Is the only solution to recode?

Comment: What if number of values in two categories differ? In that situation how the value 1 will map to value2?

Comment: You are using many to many relationship here! This will cause multiplying the rows where every member of each category will be mapped to each member of corresponding category.  E.g. in 1-5 category there will be 25 rows.  If want to map each row only once there should be some specific criteria to do that.  The desired result is very simple case and can be achieved by `cbind` also but i am sure you are not after that.

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you for your comments. You are right with your concerns. I did not think it through well enough. I should just create a new variable which specifically matches all columns. But I figured that out only after I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may create a new variable in your DT2

```
DT2$new_var <- ""
DT2$new_var[DT2$Cat_B %in% 1:5] <- "1-5"

DT2$new_var[DT2$Cat_B %in% 6:10] <- "6-10"
```

then your output will be:

```
 A tibble: 10 x 3
   Value_B Cat_B new_var
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
 1  0.771      1 1-5    
 2  0.708      2 1-5    
 3  0.142      3 1-5    
 4  0.0791     4 1-5    
 5  0.0900     5 1-5    
 6  0.343      6 6-10   
 7  0.533      7 6-10   
 8  0.393      8 6-10   
 9  0.970      9 6-10   
10  0.773     10 6-10
```

Now you can merge both the tables using common variable

hope it's useful..!